# Understanding Kafka Leader-follower architecture

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka has a leader-follower architecture. E.g., we have a Kafka cluster with 3 instances (K1, K2, K3), where K1 is the leader and K2, K3 are the followers.
The goal of the followers is to copy the updated log from the leader, and the leader is the one that can write to the log.

1. If the leader is the only broker that can read or write to the log, this does not create a bottleneck in the leader?
2. If we have producer and consumer instances, what happens if the producer sends by mistake data to a follower? The follower will ignore it, or does it relays the data to the dealer? Is this scenario possible?
3. And what will happen if the consumer tries to read data from the follower?
4. Is there any document that explains the message exchange when a failed broker restarts?

Answer (score 0):

All brokers can read/write to their own logs. There's a leader per partition, not per topic. Obviously, there's a bottleneck per machine, but it's no different than any other server's maximum I/O & network rate ; that's not a unique problem to Kafka

Under healthy conditions. It's not possible for a replica to mistakenly get data from the producer. If there's a network partition or you have unclean leader election, then the new elected leader partitions end up "winning" and overwriting other partitions

Latest versions of Kafka allow consumption from in-sync replicas

Kafka is open source, so you can follow the main method of the server and see all the threads it starts on startup and restarts